# 504 Gateway Timeout issue in expressjs while uploading file

Tags: node.js, express, http-status-code-504

Hi i am facing CORS issue in expressjs and nuxtjs while uploading files in production mode. things works fine on localhost but after i deploy to digital ocean, only one route where i upload file doesn't work.

here are the codes so far

> this is app.js

```
    const express = require('express');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const xss = require('xss-clean');
const mongoSanitize = require('express-mongo-sanitize');
const compression = require('compression');
const cors = require('cors');
const passport = require('passport');
const httpStatus = require('http-status');
const config = require('./config/config');
const morgan = require('./config/morgan');
const { jwtStrategy } = require('./config/passport');
const { authLimiter } = require('./middlewares/rateLimiter');
const routes = require('./routes/v1');
const { errorConverter, errorHandler } = require('./middlewares/error');
const ApiError = require('./utils/ApiError');

const app = express();

if (config.env !== 'test') {
  app.use(morgan.successHandler);
  app.use(morgan.errorHandler);
}

// set security HTTP headers
app.use(helmet());

// parse json request body
app.use(express.json());

// parse urlencoded request body
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// sanitize request data
app.use(xss());
app.use(mongoSanitize());

// gzip compression
app.use(compression());

// enable cors
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());

// jwt authentication
app.use(passport.initialize());
passport.use('jwt', jwtStrategy);

// limit repeated failed requests to auth endpoints
if (config.env === 'production') {
  app.use('/v1/auth', authLimiter);
}

// v1 api routes
app.use('/v1', routes);

// send back a 404 error for any unknown api request
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  next(new ApiError(httpStatus.NOT_FOUND, 'Not found'));
});

// convert error to ApiError, if needed
app.use(errorConverter);

// handle error
app.use(errorHandler);

module.exports = app;
```

> this is upload.route.js inside routes folder

```
const express = require('express');
const uploadController = require('../../controllers/uploads.controller')

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/image', uploadController.setProductImages)
router.post('/image/activity', uploadController.uploadActivityImage)

module.exports = router;
```

> this is index.js inside routes folder

```
const express = require('express');
const uploadRoute = require('./upload.route');
const config = require('../../config/config');
const router = express.Router();

const defaultRoutes = [
  {
    path: '/uploads',
    route: uploadRoute
  }
];

defaultRoutes.forEach((route) => {
  router.use(route.path, route.route);
});

module.exports = router;
```

this is the error i am getting when i upload files.

> cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at
> https://v1api.thetripclub.com/v1/uploads/image/activity. (Reason: CORS
> header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). **Status code: 504**.

```
        XHRPOSThttps://***.*******.com/v1/uploads/image/activity
        CORS Missing Allow Origin
```

[image: Error ScreenShot]

Comment: This could be because of proxy. In app.js after `const app = express();` add `app.set('trust proxy', 1);`

Comment: @Sha'an - Still not working